# Put a character at the start of a line in a file?

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a song title guessing game, where the songs are fetched from a file, one is selected at random and only the first letter of each word is printed. I am at the stage where this works but I am unsure as to how you stop one of the songs repeating without removing it altogether from the file together. My idea was the print a hashkey in front of the line, and then when it goes back round to the start check if there is a hash. if there is a hashkey, it will select another song from the list. And then at the end of the program when the user gets a guess wrong, I will strip the file of all hashkeys. I am stuck on the part where you actually insert the hashkey. So far the code goes like this:

```
file.replace(random_song, ("#") + random_song)
```

When I use this code, Python doesn't display any errors but it also doesn't change the code.
If someone can give me a pointer or suggest a more efficient way of doing it then I would be grateful

Comment: What are the values of `file` and `random_song`? Are you writing the replaced string to the file, or are you reading the file contents and operating on them?

Comment: file is a shortened version of my external file named song_names and random_song is a line in the code I picked at random earlier. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the flow of inserting `#` is as follows:

```
def insertHash(filepath, song):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read()

    lines.replace(song, ('#') + song)

    with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
        f.write(lines)
```

I think you are missing assigning the `replace()` back to the string. Replacing the `replace` line with `lines = lines.replace(song, ('#') + song)` should solve the issue.

---

Besides, you can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to store the songs that are already displayed to the user. Whenever you select a song, check if it already in the `set`. If it is, choose another. If not, insert it and display. That way, you won't be writing to a file every time.

```
shown_songs = set()

def isSongShown(song):
    return song in shown_songs

def insertSong(song):
    shown_songs.add(song)


if not isSongShown(song):
    insertSong()
    # display the song
else:
    # select a new song
```

Hope this helps!